# Ajax: How to display dynamic drop down and text box?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, textbox, dropdownbox

When I click the dropdown value of periods it should automatically display the textbox value for rate_of_interest.

Here is my model code to calculate interest value:

```
before_save :calculate_value
def calculate_value
  if self.age >= 75 && self.no_of_year == 5
    self.interest_rate == 11.75 
  elsif self.age >= 75 && self.no_of_year == 3
    self.interest_rate == 11.5
  elsif self.age >= 75 && self.no_of_year == 2
    self.interest_rate == 11
  elsif self.age >= 75 && self.no_of_year == 1
    self.interest_rate == 10.5
  elsif self.age >= 58 && self.age <= 75 && self.no_of_year == 5 
    self.interest_rate == 11.75   
  elsif self.age >= 58 && self.age <= 75 && self.no_of_year == 4
    self.interest_rate == 11.5   
  elsif self.age >= 58 && self.age <= 75 && self.no_of_year == 3 
    self.interest_rate == 11  
  elsif self.age >= 58 && self.age <= 75 && self.no_of_year == 2 
    self.interest_rate == 10.5  
  elsif self.age >= 58 && self.age <= 75 && self.no_of_year == 1 
    self.interest_rate == 10  
  elsif self.age >= 75 && self.no_of_year == 4
    self.interest_rate == 11.75
  else
    self.interest_rate
  end
end
```

According to year and age it should display the interest automatically.

my view page:

```
<h4><%= f.label :periods, class:'required' %>
<%= f.select(:no_of_year, options_for_select([['',''],['1','1'], ['2','2'],['3','3'],['4','4'],['5','5']]))%></h4>

<h4><%= f.label :interest_rate, class:'required' %>
<%= f.text_field :interest_rate, :readonly => true %></h4>
```

How and where to use ajax and javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you'll be best using [`case switch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) (in [Ruby](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/)):

```
def calculate_value
   case self.age
     when >= 75
        self.interest_rate = 10 + (0.5 * self.no_of_year) #-> algo to determine interest
     when >= 58 && <= 75
        self.interest_rate = 10 + (0.5 * self.no_of_year) #-> algo to determine interest
     else
        self.interest_rate
   end
end
```

--

**Ajax**

In order to use Ajax and Javascript, you first need to have an [endpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) to send your data to. This should be defined in the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "interest", to: "application#calculate_interest"
```

This will then allow you to use Ajax like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(".select").on("change", function() { //Binds to your select box "change" event
    $.ajax({
        url: "/interest", //Sends to your endpoint
        data: {"year": $(this).val() }
        success: function(data){
            //where the response will be processed
            $(".textfield").val = data;
        }
    });
});
```

Several caveats to the code above -

> 1. You need to be able to select the specific elements - I have just used `.select` etc - you should use an `id` tag to select them
>      individually
> 2. Your controller needs to handle the response - by using the [`respond_to`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) block:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def calculate_interest
      respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
      end
   end
end
```

---

**Update**

If you want to update the textbox from the `.on("change"` event of the `select` box:

http://jsfiddle.net/CwU33/

```
$("#test").on("change", function(){
    value = $(this).val();
    $("#text").val(value);
});

<select id="test">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="text" value="testing">
```

Comment: how to set dynamic dropdown with textbox in rails view code(without HTML coding) ?  http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/how-to-do-an-jquery-ajax-call-from-a-dropdown-using-rails/#comments -- link shows dynamic dropdown with textbox

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript ;)

Comment: im new to javascript.can you tell me how to do?